# Button datalist hack

Tags: javascript, html

I was thinking of adding an invisible button on top of a datalist option, so I could click on the datalist to trigger events. Why doesn't this work?

```
   var button=document.createElement("button")
   button.style.width=option.style.width;
   button.style.height=option.style.height;
   button.style.background="#EEEEEE"
   option.appendChild(button);
   button.onclick="clickedfriendsOption()";
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  Does the button not appear?  Does the event not trigger?

Comment: P.S. Try doing `button.onclick=clickedfriendsOption;`

Comment: button does not even appear

Comment: You can't append a button into a `<datalist>`.  It's not appearing because it's not valid to append the button there.

Comment: So what would be a way to hack this together?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Why not just listen for the `change` event on the datalist?  Wouldn't that trigger when the option was clicked?

Comment: On change does not work either, verified by this post: http://codingforums.com/javascript-programming/328492-datalist-onclick-event-not-firing.html

Comment: You can try the `<input>` element's `oninput` event.  That seems to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/L1zyavv4/

Comment: That logistically doesn't make sense, because it doesn't differentiate between selection and typing.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you then.  May I ask *why* you want to have an event when the user clicks on one of the options?  Oh!  I just thought of something.  Why not compare the input to all of the options?  If it matches, then you can maybe *assume* they clicked one of them?  Just an idea.

Comment: just creating an input friend field similar to Facebook. Could assume they clicked it, but that feels awkward.

Comment: The only other solution is to make a custom "plugin" that does this.  Create your own `<div>` that appears below the `<input>`.  I assume that's what Facebook does.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a button inside `<datalist>`, nor can you listen to events on `<option>`s.  The `<datalist>` controls the `<input>`.  So you need to listen to the `oninput` event of the `<input>` element to get what element from the `<datalist>` was selected.

```
input.addEventListener('input', clickedfriendsOption);
```

DEMO (open your console):

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<label for="test">Test:</label>
<input type="text" id="test" list="testlist">
<datalist id="testlist">
  <option value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
  <option value="Three">Three</option>
  <option value="Four">Four</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the last line in your code won't work. Do this instead:

```
button.onclick=function(){clickedfriendsOption()}
```

As you put it, clicking on your button would be like executing this function:

```
function f(){
     return "clickedfriendsOption()";   
     //Observe that "clickedfriendsOption()" is a string and not a function
}
```

Second of all, there's a much better way of making an element invisible than changing the color:

```
button.style.visibility="hidden";
```

Comment: Donald Duck, the button still doesn't appear

Comment: I thought you said that you wanted to make it invisible. If you want it to appear, write `button.style.visibility="visible"`

Comment: Well it still won't work, no matter what color I make it. according to Rocket Hazmat above, 'You can't append a button into a <datalist>. It's not appearing because it's not valid to append the button there.' So I'll have to think of another way to do this.